# fabfile doesn't see remote environment variables

Tags: python, fabric

My remote server (192.168.3.68) contains several environment variables set in my ~/.bashrc:

```
# For instance
export MY_DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

When I put `run('echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST')` in `fabfile.py`, it shows:

```
[192.168.3.68] run: echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST
[192.168.3.68] output:

Done
Disconnecting from 192.168.3.68... done.
```

I've tried adding `run('source ~/.bashrc')` immediately before the echo but nothing changes.

Why isn't the set environment variables in ~/.bashrc visible to fabfile?

What do I do to fix that because fabfile must be able to read these variables?

**UPDATE**

```
from fabric.context_managers import prefix

# This didn't work
with prefix('source /home/meandme/.bashrc'):
    run('echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST')
# This didn't work either
run('source /home/meandme/.bashrc && echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST')
```

Comment: This didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually bashrc is executed. But it gets stopped because it's not running interactively through this:

```
case $- in
     *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
esac
```

Now it works after I moved my environment variables at the top of my bashrc.

More detailed answer here https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1519

Answer (score 0):

Each call of `run` will open up a new shell and any transient commands in the previous invocation of `run` are thus lost (e.g., such as setting an environment variable).  To elide this issue, you can do two things:

Write your shell commands thusly:

```
run('source /path/to/.bashrc && echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST')
```

or Use the `prefix` context manager

```
from fabric.context_managers import prefix
with prefix('source /path/to/.bashrc'):
    run('echo $MY_DATABASE_HOST')
```

Comment: For debugging, can you try adding `run('cat /home/meandme/.bashrc')` to the beginning to check the output?